# Getting to grips with errors and flash messages

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, error-message, error

As a newbie to Craft and Craft Commerce. I wondered if someone could explain the difference between all these error codes that I have seen either in the docs, this forum or the templates and when they get set and when I should use each method in which situations? Apologies if this is a broad question...

```
{% if errors is defined %}
    <ul class="errors">
        {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}


{% if errorMessage is defined %}
   <p class="error">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
{% endif %}

{% if model and model.getErrors('firstName') %}
   <span class="error">{{ model.getErrors('firstName')|join }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be more specific without some more context for each of the snippets you post, but:

```
{% if errors is defined %}
    <ul class="errors">
        {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

That's checking if a variable named `errors` has been passed into the template, and if so it assumes it's an array and loops through the array to display each error in an unordered list.

```
{% if errorMessage is defined %}
    <p class="error">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

That's checking is a variable named `errorMessage` has been passed into the template and if so it assumes it's a string and just displays the single error message.

```
{% if model and model.getErrors('firstName') %}
   <span class="error">{{ model.getErrors('firstName')|join }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

That's checking if a variable named `model` has been passed into the template and assumes it's an instance of [BaseModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/BaseModel).  Then it calls the [getErrors](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#getErrors-detail) method of the class passing in `firstName` as a parameter to specifically check if any errors have been set on its `firstName` attribute.  If so, it will take that array of errors and display them using Twig's [join](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html) filter.