# Error Icon and DRYer Code

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, best-practice, dry

I currently have the following code as part of the address form in Craft Commerce.

```
        <label class="label" for="{{ modelName }}-firstName">First Name (*)</label>
        <input type="text" id="{{ modelName }}-firstName" {% if model and model.getErrors('firstName') %}class="has-error"{% endif %} name="{{ modelName }}[firstName]" value="{{ model ? model.firstName : '' }}">
        {% if model and model.getErrors('firstName') %}
            <span class="has-error">
                <svg role="img" class="icon" title="Error Icon">
                    <use xlink:href="/assets/img/icons.svg#icon-error"></use>
                </svg>
                {{ model.getError('firstName') }}
            </span>
        {% endif %}
```

This repeats several times for each form item (surname, address1, address2, postcode, country etc).

I also want to reuse the error code part for other areas on the website, when errors occur, be this discount code box, login form etc.

```
<span class="has-error">
    <svg role="img" class="icon" title="Error Icon">
        <use xlink:href="/assets/img/icons.svg#icon-error"></use>
    </svg>
    {{ model.getError('firstName') }} //This part will change based on application.
</span>
```

My question is how can I extract this part to ensure it is DRYer and not repeat it over and over? So if I want to change the class, the icon etc, I won't have loads of separate pieces of code to update.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Twig macros? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html

Comment: Any ideas on how I should structure this as the errors are all different types. See this article -> http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16188/getting-to-grips-with-errors-and-flash-messages